# Unable to start embedded Tomcat On EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS, and I want to deploy my SpringBoot application on My LINUX EC2 instance with the AWS S3 bucket. And for that i have created a SpringBoot Application, Uploaded my Application's jar on S3 bucket successfully, I have installed Java 1.8 on my EC2 instance, I "wget" my jar on my instance. But when I am trying to run command **java -jar <myfilename.jar>** it gives error: **org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat**.
Could you please tell me what should I do now?

[image: Error Console of linux terminal:]
Here is my POM.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ab</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootTryApplication-2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBootTryApplication-2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version> 5.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says `Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException`. It means that this particular version of `jackson-binder` library does not have this particular class.

It Looks like the version [2.6](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/tree/2.6/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc) does not have this class.But the [2.9](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/tree/2.9/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc) does.

You should use the newer versions of `jackson-databind` library. The latest version seems to be `2.11.2` as of today.

Comment: no problem. glad to help. One suggestion, can you post the exception as text instead of screenshot. so that it will help others searching.